# How to view specific rows clustering within shap and scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, shap

I have a genetic dataset where I have 600 rows of genes by 11 features I use in machine learning in a regression classification to predict disease-causing genes.

I am trying to view the hierarchical clustering of rows that is performed within the shap package. I am specifically running the shap heatmap - `shap.plots.heatmap(shap_values, max_display=11)` - and trying to view the data for the rows/genes being clustered in this plot (example plot shown here: https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/api_examples/plots/heatmap.html).

The code I run to try and get the clustering performed within shap (within the `shap.plots.heatmap()` function) is:

```
explainer = shap.Explainer(model, X)
shap_values = explainer(X)
import scipy.cluster
D = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(shap_values[:,:-1], 'sqeuclidean')
clustOrder = scipy.cluster.hierarchy.leaves_list(scipy.cluster.hierarchy.complete(D))
```

However this gives me an error at the 4th line making the D object:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

How do I change `shap_values[:,:-1]` to fix this error?

For reference, my `shap_values.shape` gives a 600x11 dataset and `type(shap_values)` gives `shap._explanation.Explanation`, unfortunately I can't give example data in this case. I've tried understanding similar stackoverflow questions that address this error, but I can't figure out how to get them working for the `shap_values` data in specific.

How can I address the error to run the hierarchical clustering? Is it that `shap_value` isn't a 2D scalar unless the classification is binary?

I've seen examples that have run from the `shap_values` with a notebook (https://github.com/suinleelab/treeexplainer-study/blob/master/notebooks/mortality/NHANES%20I%20Analysis.ipynb) that runs the code I try above yet works.

Comment: [scipy.spatial.distance.pdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) works for 2D scalar arrays, (not shap._explanation.Explanation).

Comment: Thank you for this, do you know if I'm doing regression classification can I convert shap values into a 2D scalar array or will this only work for binary classification?

Comment: No, I don't know about this shap package. You need to find some vector of features and then use, some type of embedding for your data. I am not sure if the shap Explanation is meant to be used this way. Let's wait for someone who knows the library.

Comment: @DN1 try after changing `shap_values[:,:-1]` to `shap_values.values[:,:-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @user12750353 that [scipy.spatial.distance.pdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) takes [ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) and `shap_values` is type of `shap._explanation.Explanation`

`shap_values` object as an attribute `values` which is the result in [ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) format that can be used with [scipy.spatial.distance.pdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html)

```
explainer = shap.Explainer(model, X)
shap_values = explainer(X)
import scipy.cluster
D = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(shap_values.values[:,:-1], 'sqeuclidean')
clustOrder = scipy.cluster.hierarchy.leaves_list(scipy.cluster.hierarchy.complete(D))
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much!! I would've been pretty much stuck without this help!